# Looking for a source

Tags: resource

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bw3JrfnBc7Q

I am looking for the source of the story explained in this video. By "source", I'm referring to some kind of written text, which probably would be authoritative or canonical. If there is none, does it comes from the oral tradition?

Comment: Welcome to HSE. It is better to give a visual explanation of the video here. Just in case if the video is regionally restricted and/or for better accessibility for the users here.